# Regex replace for the string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am looking for regex repalce command to replace particular strings. Suppose i want text `ss` to be replaced by `<u>ss</u>` in a HTML code. 
So if my input is    `<p style="">ss</p>` i want to see output `<p style=""><u>ss</u></p>`

But i don't want word like

`<b>Issues</b>` to get replaced like `<b>I<u>ss</u>es</b>`

So i need to put a check if its a complte word or apart of the word.

I want regex.replace for

`">ss<"` & `>   ss    <`

Any has better solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the observation that regex is not the best tool for use with HTML, you can use `\bss\b` expression to make sure there's a word boundary before and after the string that you're matching.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to use HTML parser library, parse the html and replace the tags.
Checkout [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Having said that if you still insist on using Regex because you know your data is in particular format then following regex should suffice for your need.

```
[>]\s?ss\s?[<]
```

- [>] is close tag
- [<] is open tag
- \s is optional white space
- ss is the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You should not used Regex to parse html, regex is designed for regular lagnuages, where HTML is context free.

I would strongly suggest a [HTML Dom Parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
  string input = "<p style="">ss</p>  <b>Issues</b>";
  string pattern = "(?<=\>)ss(?=\<)";
  string replacement = "<u>ss</u>";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple solution like this:

```
public string ReplaceHtmlTagContent(string value, string search) {
    return value.Replace(">" + search + "<", "><u>" + replace + "</u><")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I exactly understand what you want here, but what's wrong with this:

```
dataString = dataString.Replace(">ss<", "><u>ss</u><").Replace("> ss <", "><u> ss </u><");
```